# Symfony - ChoiceType return

Tags: php, symfony, select, drop-down-menu

I made a request for a form but cannot define ChoiceType for select option for Actions Field.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('title', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Label1', 'attr' => ['class'=>'form-control']))
        ->add('actions', ChoiceType::class, array('a' => 'Option 1', 'b' => 'Option 2','c' => 'Option 3'))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Send', 'attr' => [
            'class' => 'btn btn-primary action-save'
        ]))
        ->getForm();
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices

```
 $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('title', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Label1', 'attr' => ['class'=>'form-control']))
        ->add('actions', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices' => array('a' => 'Option 1', 'b' => 'Option 2','c' => 'Option 3')

        ))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Send', 'attr' => [
            'class' => 'btn btn-primary action-save'
        ]))
        ->getForm();
```